# A way to use an array instead of a t.string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have the following objects:

```
create_table :expenses do |t|
    t.belongs_to  :user, index: true

    t.string :ref
    t.string :days
    t.string :traject_names
    t.string :nb_kms
    t.string :parkings
    t.string :trains
    t.string :taxis
    t.string :metros
    t.string :meals
    t.string :hotels
    t.string :natures
    t.string :amounts
    t.string :o_ns
    t.string :clients
    t.timestamps
end
```

I'd like to store an array in each of them. Should I use `serialize` ?

It would be something like this:

```
@expense = Expense.create(ref: @current_date, days: {["Monday 01"], ["Tuesday 02"]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@expense = Expense.create(ref: @current_date, days: ["Monday 01", "Tuesday 02"])
```

This way it is array of days, you only need to add `serialize` to your model, and it will take care of formatting data when reading/writing

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :days
end
```

It will be stored as a string in `db` but when you get value of `days` you will get `Array` and can then use any `Array` method.

Comment: This is what I did. However when I tried to fill my variable I get the following error:

`syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...ref: @current_date, days:{[""], ["3"], ["4"]}) ... ^ Documents/tools/intranet/app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end ...urrent_date, days:{[""], ["3"], ["4"]}) ... ^`

`:ref` is a string and has not been serialized.

Comment: Have you tried like in my post `days: ["Monday 01", "Tuesday 02"]`